# Vue watcher triggered on creating sibling property

Tags: vue.js

I'm experiencing problems with vue watchers.

How to explain such behavior: watcher on `test.a` is triggered on **creating** `test.b` property?

```js
vm = new Vue({
  data: {
    test: { a: {}, c: {} }
  }
})
vm.$watch('test.a', () => {console.log('> test.a changed')})
vm.$watch('test.b', () => {console.log('> test.b changed')})
vm.$watch(() => vm.test.c, () => {console.log('> test.c changed')}, {deep: true})

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('creating: test.b')
  Vue.set(vm.test, 'b', {})
}, 10)

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('changing: test.b')
  vm.test.b = 1
}, 20)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.min.js"></script>
```

EDIT:

In real world I use deep watchers, but such behavior was observed for both: **normal** and **deep** watcher types.

*Creating new property triggers all sibbling deep watches* and in most cases normal watches.

Comment: It turns out that this is a known issue in Vue 2: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/5776. Vue 3 doesn't suffer from this.

Answer (score 0):

`Vue.set(vm.test, 'b', {})` this is triggering a change in `test` just once.

```js
   vm = new Vue({
      data: {
        test: { a: {}, b: {}}
      }
    })
    vm.$watch('test.a', () => {console.log('> test.a changed', vm.test)}, {deep: true})
    vm.$watch('test.b', () => {console.log('> test.b changed', vm.test.b)}, {deep: true})
    setTimeout(() => {
  Vue.set(vm.test, 'b', {name: 1})
    }, 1000)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

using `deep: true` and `test: {a: {}, b: {}}` should solve the problem

Comment: If you run the code and see, `> test.b changed` is being consoled on changing `test.b`

Comment: Nope, I'm not seeing that. I only see `creating: test.b` and `changing: test.b`, but the actual watchers are not triggered.

Comment: what do you mean when you say actual watchers? Are we trying to trigger the change from somewhere else as well?

Comment: `> test.b changed` is not being logged. Check the console?

Comment: I am having issue on creating sibling property dynamically, not changing it

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use a function that returns the JSON of the nested object, instead of using a dot-delimited path:

```
vm.$watch(
  // The first function returns the JSON representation of the object
  () => JSON.stringify(vm.test.a),

  // Handler
  () => console.log('> test.a changed')
);
```

However, for the case of `vm.test.b`, which may be undefined at runtime, then you will need to use the new [null-coalescing operator `??`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) that is [supported by some modern browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-javascript_operators_nullish_coalescing):

```
vm.$watch(
  // The first function returns the JSON representation of the object
  () => JSON.stringify(vm.test.b ?? {}),

  // Handler
  () => console.log('> test.a changed')
);
```

If you want backwards compatibility, you can use a more verbose check, i.e.:

```
vm.$watch(
  // The first function returns the JSON representation of the object
  () => JSON.stringify(vm.test.b === void 0 ? {} : vm.test.b),

  // Handler
  () => console.log('> test.a changed')
);
```

```js
vm = new Vue({
  data: {
    test: {
      a: {}
    }
  }
})
vm.$watch(
  () => JSON.stringify(vm.test.a),
  () => console.log('> test.a changed')
);
vm.$watch(
  () => JSON.stringify(vm.test.b === void 0 ? {} : vm.test.b),
  () => console.log('> test.b changed')
);

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('creating: test.b')
  Vue.set(vm.test, 'b', {})
}, 10)

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('changing: test.b')
  vm.test.b = 1
}, 20)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This bahaves the same as in question if I make deep watch `$watch(... , {deep:true})`. Watching new created element after its creation is not a problem, but my problem that it triggers all sibling watches

Comment: @Darius This doesn't trigger sibling watches: have you checked the console?

Comment: In such case yes, but my real case is much more complex and I use **deep watchers**, but such behavior i could reproduce with both watcher types and your example does not work with **deep watchers**. `JSON.strigify` would be performance issue on big data structures

Comment: @Darius If that's the case, update your question with the necessary details. The last time I checked there is no mention of deep watchers in your original question.